# How do I resolve this error. Am trying to connect to firebase

Tags: firebase

Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.

Comment: Seems your issue isn't with firebase, but gradle.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many of the solutions but finally I have resolved this error
Check out my Screenshots and configure it in similar way.
If you are using new Android Studio or any recent version you will **not find jcenter in recent version** in your build-gradle file.

[**build-gradle[project]**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoupA.png)

[**build-gradle[app]**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NpEv.png)

[**Dependencies in App level gradle**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnCaN.png)

In settings.gradle comment out jcenter
[**Settings.gradle**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Feem5.png)

Project Structure Settings
[**Project Structure Settings**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P2rc.png)
[**Project Structure Settings 2**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1f4U.png)

Hope this will solve your error.